# Analyzing POST request PhoneGap

Tags: xcode, networking, cordova

I am making an app using PhoneGap and I am sending a POST request to a web service. Now I need to analyze the request that is being sent. What tool should I use to do that - Wireshark ?

I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to see what the post looks like is to post it to something like http://requestb.in/. That way you can test it from your app itself. Bascially change where your posting to, to the post bin you create.

Comment: You are able to see what the content posted from your app. If it posts to the bin and the expected output is correct, then your good to go. Now if you want to see what the request looks like that the service is sending back, then you can just test that locally or have the app itself output the content.

Answer (score 0):

Wire shark can do that but its does lot more than monitoring HTTP based requests.

Try using **Fiddler** for that.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using mac and fiddler doesn't work on that